Unable to include legend in KMZ when using ArcGIS Pro MapToKML tool
I've followed the instructions on the MapToKML tool page(https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/map-to-kml.htm), but I'm having no luck with including a legend overlay when opening the kmz in Google Earth.
# Specify the path to your .aprx file
aprx_path = r"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth\GoogleEarth_Block_and_Roads_KML\GoogleEarth_Block_and_Roads_KML.aprx"

# Open the ArcGIS Pro project
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_path)

# Set the output path for the KML/KMZ file
output_kmz = rf"\\bctsdata.bcgov\data\tst_root\LOCAL_DATA\GoogleEarth_Blocks_and_Roads_KML\GoogleEarth_Blocks_and_Roads_{date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')}.kmz"

# Get map in the project
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]
print(f"Located map: {map.name}")

# Get layout in the project
layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
    
# Export the group layer to KML/KMZ
try:
    arcpy.conversion.MapToKML(map, output_kmz, "300000", '', '', '', '', '', '', layout.name)
    print(f"Exported all layers to {output_kmz}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to export layers: {e}")
    print("***Unsuccessful attempt - terminating script***")
    sys.exit()
    
# Clean up
del aprx

